# partial regex checking return false on using find method

Tags: java, regex

i have a input 000.100.112 which giving false on input to the given below code,I just need partial check if exists return true
partial check is working in

```
     String emailRegex="/^(000\\.000\\.|000\\.100\\.1|000\\.[36])/";
    Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
    Matcher m = thePattern.matcher(data);
    if (m.matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return m.find();
```

i expect true on partial check ,but it gives false
[image]
  it gives a match in this online regex checking

Comment: `/` are not part of regex. They're regex delimiters in Perl and Javascript. You're not programming Javascript but Java.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus A bunch of languages use delimiters (e.g. PHP).

Comment: @Mark Jernimus thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Java regex patterns do not take forward slash delimiters, as they might in other languages such as PHP.  Also, since you want a *partial* match, you should be using the following pattern:

```
^(000\.000\.|000\.100\.1|000\.[36]).*
                                  ^^^^ necessary
```

Note carefully the `.*` at the end of the pattern, without which a partial match won't work.

```
String emailRegex="^(000\\.000\\.|000\\.100\\.1|000\\.[36]).*";
Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
Matcher m = thePattern.matcher("000.100.112");
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

**Edit:**

As @MarkMobius pointed out, you could also use your original pattern with `Matcher#find()`:

```
String emailRegex="^(000\\.000\\.|000\\.100\\.1|000\\.[36])";
Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
Matcher m = thePattern.matcher("000.100.112");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Comment: Not 'necessary' if you use `find()` instead of `matches()`

Answer (score 0):

Your online regex tester uses the JavaScript regex literal. In JavaScript, regexes can be delimited by `/.../`. Those `/` at the start and end that you see in the online regex tester are not actually part of the regex pattern. They are like the quote marks in a Java string.

The quote marks in `"string"` is not part of the string. Likewise, the slashes in `/someregex/` is not part of the regex.

Therefore, when you use your regex in Java, you should not include those slashes:

```
String emailRegex="^(000\\.000\\.|000\\.100\\.1|000\\.[36])";
```

If you do, they will be interpreted as if you wanted to literally match slashes.